# ListView do banco de dados Android - Fecha aplicação com erro

Tags: java, android, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou implementando um cadastro com SQLite3 no Android e até aqui tudo bem, o problema está na chamada da `Activity` de listagem de dados quando o cadastro é realizado com sucesso, ao fazer a chamada a `Activity` a aplicação é fechada com erro.

Segue código:

## DevedorActivity

```
package br.com.savemoney.mastercontas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.com.savemoney.database.DatabaseHelper;

public class DevedorActivity extends Activity {

  private DatabaseHelper helper;
  private EditText edtNomeDevedor, edtTelefoneDevedor, edtEmailDevedor;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.devedor);

    edtNomeDevedor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNomeDevedor);
    edtTelefoneDevedor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTelefoneDevedor);
    edtEmailDevedor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmailDevedor);

    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
  }

  public void cadastrarDevedor(View view) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("nome", edtNomeDevedor.getText().toString());
    values.put("telefone", edtTelefoneDevedor.getText().toString());
    values.put("email", edtEmailDevedor.getText().toString());

    long resultado = db.insert("devedor", null, values);
    if(resultado != -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.cadastro_devedor_sucesso, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ListaDevedoresActivity.class));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.cadastro_devedor_erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    helper.close();
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

## ListarDevedoresActivity

```
package br.com.savemoney.mastercontas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.com.savemoney.database.DatabaseHelper;

public class ListaDevedoresActivity extends Activity {

  private DatabaseHelper helper;
  private SQLiteDatabase db;
  private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
  ListView listViewDevedores;

  private static final String[] campos = new String[] {"_id", "nome"};

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_devedores);

    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    listViewDevedores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDevedores);

    listarDevedores();
  }

  public void listarDevedores(){
    //executa consulta geral de todos os registros cadastrados no banco de dados
    Cursor devedores = db.query("agenda", campos, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (devedores.getCount() > 0){
        //cria cursor que será exibido na tela, nele serão exibidos 
        //todos os contatos cadastrados
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_devedor, devedores, campos, new int[] { R.id.txtIdDevedor, R.id.txtNomeDevedor});

        //relaciona o dataSource ao próprio listview
        listViewDevedores.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nenhum registro encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();     

    //fecha a conexão com o Banco de dados
    db.close();        
   }
}
```

**LogCat**

Aqui, peguei só a parte de erro... Vejam se conseguem ver alguma coisa!

```
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971): Process:
> br.com.savemoney.mastercontas, PID: 1971 06-19 14:21:08.579:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity
> ComponentInfo{br.com.savemoney.mastercontas/br.com.savemoney.mastercontas.ListaDevedoresActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 06-19 14:21:08.579:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 06-19
> 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 06-19
> 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 06-19 14:21:08.579:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 06-19
> 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-19
> 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 06-19 14:21:08.579:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 06-19
> 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-19 14:21:08.579:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1971): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> br.com.savemoney.mastercontas.ListaDevedoresActivity.listarDevedores(ListaDevedoresActivity.java:35)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> br.com.savemoney.mastercontas.ListaDevedoresActivity.onCreate(ListaDevedoresActivity.java:30)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 06-19
> 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
> 06-19 14:21:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):   ... 11 more
```

Alguém consegue ver onde está o erro? De já obrigado.

Comment: Que erro é mostrado no log quando isso acontece?

Comment: O que retorna no log Cat? provavelmente vai mostrar a linha que está com problema ou algum erro.

Comment: Post abaixo o logcat... no aguardo...

Comment: `Cursor devedores = db.query("agenda", campos, null, null, null, null, null);` verifique os valores nesse trecho de código a exception começou na linha 30 e jogou pra 35.

Answer (score 1):

É um **NullPointerException**, ou seja, existe uma variável com valor nulo.

A melhor forma de resolver *erros em tempo de execução*, como é o caso do **NullPointerException**, é debugando o código.

Procure na pilha do erro referências aos seus arquivos fonte e a linhas que originou o erro.

Por exemplo:
*ExemploActivity:96*.

Coloque um ponto de parada antes da linha indicada (96), rode o debug e inspecione os valores de suas variáveis, passo a passo.

Não vale a pena ficar pressupondo o que aconteceu, é mais fácil partir logo para a ação.

**DICA**: No onCreate, em vez de recuperar somente à referencia dos seus componentes visuais (*findViewById*), trate também os seus valores.

Exemplo:

```
EditText edtNomeDevedor = (EditText) edtNomeDevedor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNomeDevedor);
String nomeDevedor = edtNomeDevedor.getText().toString() == null ? "": edtNomeDevedor.getText().toString();
```

Dessa forma você trata o valor, que pode estar vindo nulo, já na criação da sua atividade (Activity).

Boa sorte!